# Momentum modes in antiperiodic boundary condition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, boundary-conditions

Fermions with antiperiodic boundary conditions have momentum in the form $$\frac{n \pi}{L}$$ where $n=-(L-1)...-1,1,...(L-1)$, i.e. odd integers. I am dealing with a Hamiltonian in momentum space with an interaction term of the form $\sum_{k_1, k_2,q}V_0(k_1,k_2,q)c_{k_1}^{\dagger}c_{k_2}^{\dagger}c_{k_2-q}c_{k_1+q}$.Now if you see if I take $k_1$ and $q$ from the momentum values of apbc , then on adding it gives me an even integer which is not a momentum contained in this boundary condition. What am I doing wrong? Did I make a mistake while writing down the Hamiltonian in momentum space itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The momentum transfer $q$ has to be an *even* integral multiple of $\pi/L$. There is no need for it be in the allowed momenum lattice.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot $q=k_3-k_4$ while doing the Fourier transform, bad question.